# Exporting to excel with carriage returns

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

I am trying to export to excel from my `Datagrid`. The `Datagrid` has a column where we put comments in. In that column the comments are put on separate lines. When it exports to excel it exports in multiple rows.

Here is how it looks in my `DataGrid`:

[image: Data Grid]

Here is how it looks when I export to Excel:

[image: Excel Export]

Here is the code that I am using to do it:

```
public static void CreateExcelFromClipboard(string worksheetName, string fullFilePath, bool toOpen)
        {
            //Excel Application class 
            _Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            //Get process id
            int excelProcessId = GetApplicationProcessId(app);

            try
            {
                //Add workbook
                Workbook theWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
                //Add worksheet
                var theWorksheet =
                    (Worksheet)theWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                theWorksheet.Name = worksheetName;
                app.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
                app.DisplayAlerts = false;
                theWorksheet.Activate();

                //Paste to the worksheet from clpboard
                theWorksheet.Paste(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                //Apply Borders
                ApplyBorder(theWorksheet.UsedRange);

                //Auto Fit All columns
                Range xlRange = theWorksheet.UsedRange;
                // put all hardcodes in  a constant class 
                xlRange.Font.Name = "Arial";
                xlRange.Font.Size = 9;
                var firstRowRange = (Range)xlRange.Rows[1, Missing.Value];
                firstRowRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
                firstRowRange.EntireRow.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                //Set Wrap Test to false
                xlRange.WrapText = true;
                xlRange.Columns.AutoFit();
                theWorksheet.Activate();

                //Save the file
                theWorkbook.SaveAs(fullFilePath, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                if (!toOpen)
                {
                    //Clean up 
                    app.Quit();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ForceExcelClose(excelProcessId);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                app.Visible = toOpen;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you try to increase the height of the first row in exported Excel file? To be sure that the text is realy in the separate rows and not just overlaps rows.

Comment: would that be assuming all the rows are the same height - right now its just using the copy paste method - I would then have to populate the worksheet cell by cell?